# Google Two Step Verification

Tags: security, google-accounts

We use Google Apps and we've implemented two step verification in our Organization.

An issue we have is all of us use the various computers in the meeting rooms to view our drive / email at times and we have to always make sure we have our phones with us - we make a habit of telling employees to leave phones at their desks during meetings.

Is there a way to white list an IP or a group of computers so they'll always be approved for a domain inside Google's Two-Step verification?

Comment: What might be easier is to use a program called WinAuth.  I presume you have to log into the machine, in order to use it, and you can password protect the data.  Any event WinAuth allows you to have a Google Authenticator on your desktop.  All you need is the secret code/barcode image url to import it.

Comment: "is there a way to white list an IP or a group of computers so they'll always be approved for a domain inside Google's Two-Step verification?" - This would defeat the security of 2-Factor Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

The point of Two Factor Authentication (2FA) as implemented in this case is that you have two factors: *something you know* (the password) and *something you have* (the phone). You can't leave out the second factor.

You could, however, create another *something you have*, such as a device with any TOTP app. Ramhound suggested [WinAuth](https://winauth.com/) in the comments, but I haven't used it and I can't vouch that it's secure. Remember that it must be something that **only you** have.

Anyway, the proper usage of 2FA would be to **bring the *something you have* with you**.